# SQL Server create list of geographic points from distance and starting point

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis

I can do this in C# but not in SQL Server and for what I need I really really want this to be a function in my SQL Server database!

I have a starting point `LatX` and `LonX` which is stored as a Geographic point. I want to create a list (rows in a table etc) of lat and lon pairs from that point at X degrees (0, 90, 180 etc) at intervals of Z meters for a set distance Max (meters). I just can't work out how to do it in SQL Server.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you looking for, 
But you can bring your c# function into SQL, 
here a nice post describing how to import CLR functions,

https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/March-2013/CLR-Functions-in-SQL-Server-A-Tutorial